# IF Formula where X = an unidentified (but stable) number

Tags: google-sheets

All I want is that my clients be able to put an "x" in the tasks they want performed. Each has an associated cost, which I would like to sum in Q4 (I will be dragging the formula down through subsequent cells).

[image: screenshot]

I know I will have to include "SUM" in the formula, but I cannot even get it to accept a second number added to the first:

```
=IF(G4 = "x", ".25"; H4 = "x" ".75"+G4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:F3="x",VALUE(RIGHT(A$1:F$1,4)))))
```

### Explained

The `RIGHT` formula extracts the value from the title. The `VALUE` formula converts the string into a number. The `IF` formula will display the value, only if an `x` is present.  The `ARRAYFORMULA` takes on the complete range and the `SUM` formula performs the summation.

### Example

I've created an example for you: **[SUM where X](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIgRZFv7hcn71sPVJ-MChL8Zd8f2Y6xz6tfT8acPW4Y/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

The requirement crops up often and a function has been provided specifically for such purposes, [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294):

```
 =sumproduct(A$2:P$2,A3:P3="x")
```

Assumes that there are values only in A2:P2 (say any descriptions for them moved to the row above).